# Azure APIM - API path issue when in a version set

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating a APIM version set with 2 APIs:

1. sample-data/v1
2. sample-data/v2

Both with same path `sample-data` but different version of the API (v1 & v2).

Below is my Terraform configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sample_data_api_v1" {
  name                = "sample-data-api-v1"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.boxrg.name
  api_management_name = module.api001.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "sample Data API v1"
  path                = "sample-data"
  protocols           = ["https"]
  version             = "v1"
  version_set_id      = azurerm_api_management_api_version_set.sample-data-api-version-set.id
  import {
    content_format = "openapi"
    content_value  = templatefile("${path.module}/template-files/api-spec/sample-data-v1-openapi.yml", {})
  }

}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sample_data_api_v2" {
  name                = "sample-data-api-v2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.boxrg.name
  api_management_name = module.api001.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "sample Data API v2"
  path                = "sample-data"
  protocols           = ["https"]
  version             = "v2"
  version_set_id      = azurerm_api_management_api_version_set.sample-data-api-version-set.id
  import {
    content_format = "openapi"
    content_value  = templatefile("${path.module}/template-files/api-spec/sample-data-v2-openapi.yml", {})
  }
}
```

However this is complaining that the path `sample-data` already exist. as below:

*Error: waiting on creating/updating Api: (Name "sample-data-api-v1" / Service Name "....." / Resource Group "....."): Future#WaitForCompletion:
the number of retries has been exceeded: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ValidationError"
Message="One or more fields contain incorrect values:"
Details=[{"code":"ValidationError","message":"API with specified URL path 'sample-data' already exists.","target":"path"}]*

I can do this manually via portal, no problem. Only happens via Terraform.
I am failing to understand where the issue is because despite having same path, they shouldnt conflict as the Terraform/Azure appends the version to the URI path making them different:

eg.

1. /sample-data/**v1**/
2. /sample-data/**v2**/

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug somewhere?
Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same issue through azure DevOps.

Comment: @DIBYARANJANTRIPATHY - Can you try setting `source_api_id` and leave out `display_name`, `path` and `protocols`. 
That did for us.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api